# Google script inject html into html email

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a loop that will inject a html component into my html email using google script editor. I keep getting **errors: 
   [ { message: 'Syntax error: Illegal character. line: 51 file: Code',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'badRequest' } ] }**. How do you do this.

Path: `Javascript.js`

```
var data = [{name: 'Bob', link: 'www.test.com'}, {name: 'Joe', link: 'www.test.com'}];

var htmlComponent = [];
for (var = x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {
  var component = `<tr><td><a href=x.link>x.name</a></td></tr>`;
  htmlComponent.push(component);
}
```

Path: `htmlEmail.html`

```
<body>
  <center>
    <table
      style="width:100%;max-width:600px;margin: 0 auto;"
      cellpadding="0"
      cellspacing="0"
      border="0"
    >
      <tbody>
          <?= htmlComponent ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind trying an alternate method (based on the [templated HTML guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates))

`Code.js`:

```
function mailThis() {
  var htmlString = doGet();
  GmailApp.sendEmail('To', 'Subject', '', {
    htmlBody: htmlString.getContent()
  })
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate();
}
```

`Index.html`:

```
<body>
  <center>
      <table
      style="width:100%;max-width:600px;margin: 0 auto;"
      cellpadding="0"
      cellspacing="0"
      border="0"
      >
      <tbody>
      <? var data = [{name: 'Bob', link: 'www.bobwebsite.com'}, {name: 'Joe', link: 'www.joewebsite.com'}];
      for (var x = 0; x <= 1; x++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href=<?= data[x].link ?> > <?= data[x].name ?> </a></td>
        </tr>
        <? } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

- You want to create a HTML table from an array and put the created table the existing HTML.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

  - In your situation, `Javascript.js` and `htmlEmail.html` are put in each file on the script editor.
  - `Javascript.js` is Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Usage:

When you use this modified script, please copy and paste `Javascript.js` and `htmlEmail.html` to a script file and HTML file of the script editor, respectively. And run `myFunction()`. By this, you can see HTML including the table at the log. When `html` is used for `MailApp.sendEmail({to: "###", subject: "sample subject", htmlBody: html})`, an email with the HTML body is sent.

#### For `Javascript.js`

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = [{name: 'Bob', link: 'www.test.com'}, {name: 'Joe', link: 'www.test.com'}];

  // I modified below script
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlEmail"); // Retrieve HTML from the file of htmlEmail.html.
  t.htmlComponent = data.reduce(function(s, x) {return s += "<tr><td><a href=" + x.link + ">" + x.name + "</a></td></tr>"}, "");
  var html = t.evaluate().getContent();

  Logger.log(html)

  // If you want to send an email including HTML, please use the following script.
  // MailApp.sendEmail({to: "###", subject: "sample subject", htmlBody: html});
}
```

#### For `htmlEmail.html`

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
<?= htmlComponent ?>
```

To:

```
<?!= htmlComponent ?>
```

### Note:

- In the current stage, unfortunately, the back-tick and the template literals cannot be used at Google Apps Script.

### References:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)
- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.