# Capture HTML Form Responses in Google Sheets and send a Confirmation Email to the Form Submitter

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I want the script to send the created html email template email.html to the person who last submitted the form.

Below is the success message I get in the console:

[image: Apps Script Console]

Below is the actual email that is received by the person who submits the form:

[image: Email]

The email.html is formatted correctly and appears perfectly when sent manually.

I hope this is reprex enough.

**EDIT: Maybe it's easier if I include the code**

```
function sendEmail () {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();
var data = ss.getRange(lr,3);
var email = data.getValue();

var message = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email');
var subject = "Test Subject"
GmailApp.sendEmail(email,subject, message);
}
```

Comment: You said `I succeed in capturing form responses in google sheets using the onSubmit trigger.` But most users capture there own form responses using doGet() or  doPost() or even google.script.run

Comment: Where is your html form code?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question needs more focus. In other words, don't include code that isn't directly causing the issue / problem. Ref. [mcve].

Comment: @Cooper please see the last bit of code added to the explanation. I'm open to a completely different approach. My goal is to capture html form submission in a google sheet and fire off a thank you email to the submitter when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Rubén Apologies for the bulk of info. I'm not a dev, I have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: No problem Ramon, but it's still required that the question fits the site guidelines. Start by creating a [mcve] (the idea of  creating a "mcve" is to find where the problem is and/or what you have to learn)

Comment: @Rubén I have adapted my question to what I believe to be minimally reprex. Let me know if I need to make it more specific. Thanks for the responses so far!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are using `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile`, but from the image it's clear there at least one error, the script misses two methods:

- `HtmlService.HtmlTemplate.evaluate()` to evaluate the Templated HTML
- `HtmlService.HtmlOutput.getContent()` to get the HTML from the `HtmlService.HtmlOutput` object returned by the previous method.

Another option that looks to be an error is the use of `GmailApp.sendEmail(string,string,string)` method, as the third parameter should be a string to be used as the email plain text content. If you want to pass HTML, instead use `GmailApp.sendEmail(string,string,string, Object)`

Related

- [Emailing Google Sheet range (with or without formatting) as a HTML table in a Gmail message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36529890/1595451)
- [Sending an email in HTML and plain with a Gmail Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45883782/1595451)
- [Google script inject html into html email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57764976/1595451)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)

Answer (score 0):

This script will work fine.
[click here](https://github.com/nasarlalu/html-form-to-google-sheet-with-notification/blob/main/sheet_script.js)
or go to this repository https://github.com/nasarlalu/html-form-to-google-sheet-with-notification/tree/main

You need to add a new trigger and select doPost function in it. and deploy it as new deployment. Then use the deployment URL for the form submission.